# Azure AD B2C password expiration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We leverage **Azure AD B2C** in our solution with a "sign up or sign in" policy. On a regular basis (I have not counted the exact number of days), when I try to login, I got : "invalid username or password". I have to reset my password to make it work.

So I have two questions :

- **Is there a default password expiration policy**? One of the feature request on Azure B2C Connect is to enable the definition of such custom expiration policy but I have not found in the documentation the fact that a default one was in place. Is there any way to remove this default behavior (i.e. no expiration)?
- The **message "invalid username or password" is misleading** and should be "your password has expired". Any way to change that ?

Thx !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there a default password expiration policy?

## For B2C Local accounts:

*NOTE:Local accounts can only be created by sign-up or AAD Graph API. You cannot create it by clicking New users in AAD which is a B2C tenant.*

**There is no password expiration policy for local accounts by default.** Azure AD B2C's sign-up, sign-up or sign-in and password reset policies use the "strong" password strength and don't expire any passwords **for local accounts** in Azure AD B2C. You can see this in [this FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs#what-password-policy-is-used-for-local-accounts-in-azure-ad-b2c).

Howerver, there are also some conditions which you may come across the B2C local account users password expiration.

- Defaultly, if a local account is created by built-in password policy, then this policy sets the `passwordPolicies` property to `DisablePasswordExpiration`. So the passwords of B2C local users won't expire.
- However, if a local account is created by either a custom policy or Azure AD Graph API, then you have to set the `passwordPolicies` property to be `DisablePasswordExpiration` manually.

So, If your local users' passwords may expire after 90 days without notification if you don't set the property of the Password policy to be `DisablePasswordExpiration`.

> Is there any way to remove this default behavior (i.e. no expiration)? The message "invalid username or password" is misleading and should be "your password has expired". Any way to change that?

## Resolution for local accounts:

1. You can refer to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#create-consumer-user-accounts) to create B2C local users without password expiration via AAD Graph API:

   ```
   POST https://graph.windows.net/contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6
   Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjdkRC1nZWNOZ1gxWmY3R0xrT3ZwT0IyZGNWQSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJod...
   Content-Type: application/json
   Content-Length: 338
   {
   // All of these properties are required to create consumer users.
   "accountEnabled": true,
   "signInNames": [                            // controls which identifier the user uses to sign in to the account
       {
           "type": "emailAddress",             // can be 'emailAddress' or 'userName'
           "value": "joeconsumer@gmail.com"
       }
   ],
   "creationType": "LocalAccount",            // always set to 'LocalAccount'
   "displayName": "Joe Consumer",                // a value that can be used for displaying to the end user
   "mailNickname": "joec",                        // an email alias for the user
   "passwordProfile": {
       "password": "P@ssword!",
       "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false   // always set to false
   },
   "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
   }
   ```
2. Update the Password Polices's property of affected users to be `DisablePasswordExpiration` with **`PATCH`** method via AAD Graph API, you can refer to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#UpdateUser) to update your b2c users.
3. Ask all affected B2C users to change their passwords.

---

## For Social accounts:

The password expiration depends on the Identity provider's password policy. [AAD can also be an identity provider in AAD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom).

AAD Password Expiration policies that apply only to **work or school accounts**. The available password policy settings that can be applied to user accounts that are created and managed in Azure AD.

So, if you make the AAD as a social account for the AAD B2C, the Password Expiration policies will affect those social accounts.

## Resolution for AAD social accounts:

If your account is a social account in Azure AD, connect to that Tenant using your company administrator credentials.
Execute one of the following commands:

1. To set the password of one user to never expire, run the following cmdlet by using the user principal name (UPN) or the user ID of the user: `Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName <user ID> -PasswordNeverExpires $true`
2. To set the passwords of all the users in an organization to never expire, run the following cmdlet: `Get-MSOLUser | Set-MsolUser -PasswordNeverExpires $true`

You can see more details about Password Policy in Azure AD  in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-passwords-policy).

Comment: Hello @Wayne and thanks for this explanation. In my case, I am both the global admin AND a local account user for the B2C directory. So I guess in this case, the password expiration policy applies and that is why I am seeing my password expire every 30 days... What about my second question on the error text ? Thx !

Comment: Hi, @ben , Have you created custom policies for AD B2C? Your password expires every 30 days, but the default time is 90 days. Have you set any other SSRS policies?

Comment: You are right, I think it is every 90 days (as I said in my original question, I have not counted the days). Any idea for the misleading text (it seems to be only true for the built in "sign up and sign in" policy not for "the sign in" policy ?

Comment: If this issue is about the password expiration, I think that the misleading text could not be changed. I didn't came across my password expiration. Azure AD should shows Password has expired . "Invalid username or password" shouldn't be for this scense.