# Remove password expiration on b2c custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using B2C custom policies for local and social accounts. I understand that with custom policies the password expires in 90 days and I can remove expiration for each user individually with this procedures:
[Azure AD B2C password expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051521/azure-ad-b2c-password-expiration)
But I want to update the custom policy so new users have the no expiration behavior.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!
Germán

Answer (score 0):

To disable expiration of passwords, you must set the **passwordPolicies** property of [the **user** object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) to "DisablePasswordExpiration", as follows:

1) Declare the **passwordPolicies** [claim type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#claimtype):

```xml
<ClaimType Id="passwordPolicies">
  <DisplayName>Password Policies</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

2) Default the **passwordPolicies** claim to "DisablePasswordExpiration" when the user account is created:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
  <PersistedClaims>
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration" />
  </PersistedClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Refer to [the custom policy starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) for examples of this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I already have that configuration. But when I create a new user and check the expiration:
 Get-MSOLUser -ObjectId <object-id> |  Select PasswordNeverExpires
It doesnt return True