# Azure AD B2C is possible set password expiration period?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I see that in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051521/azure-ad-b2c-password-expiration) default password expiration period is 90 days.

But is there any way to change this period, for example to 30 days or 1 day? or any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using [a custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom).

[Here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-after-90-days) is an example of a policy that forces an existing user to change their current password after 90 days (which can be changed to a lesser or greater number of days).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the suggestion mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758050/ad-b2c-forcechangepasswordnextlogin-for-user-flow-sign-in-v2-doesnt-initiate) thread.

[Remove password expiration on b2c custom policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780878/remove-password-expiration-on-b2c-custom-policies)

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.

Comment: thank you, but the point of my issue in configuring period, not in how to remove expiration.